# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el mismo resultado de DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes que tengo en .NET C # pero en Node js?

Tags: c#, nodejs, .net, encriptación

Necesito obtener en Node js el mismo valor descifrado que obtengo de mi sitio web en .NET C #

Mi código en la clase .NET C # llamado Crypto es:

```
private static readonly string key = "Z8,omB0pxZwñ3h9s";

public string Encrypt(string data)
{
    string encData = null;
    byte[][] keys = GetHashKeys(key);

    try
    {
        encData = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(data, keys[0], keys[1]);
        return encData;
    }
    catch (CryptographicException) {
        return null;
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException) {
        return null;
    }
}

public string Decrypt(string data)
{
    string decData = null;
    byte[][] keys = GetHashKeys(key);

    try
    {
        decData = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(data, keys[0], keys[1]);
    }
    catch (CryptographicException) { }
    catch (ArgumentNullException) { }

    return decData;
}

private byte[][] GetHashKeys(string key)
{
    byte[][] result = new byte[2][];
    Encoding enc = Encoding.UTF8;

    SHA256 sha2 = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();

    byte[] rawKey = enc.GetBytes(key);
    byte[] rawIV = enc.GetBytes(key);

    byte[] hashKey = sha2.ComputeHash(rawKey);
    byte[] hashIV = sha2.ComputeHash(rawIV);

    Array.Resize(ref hashIV, 16);

    result[0] = hashKey;
    result[1] = hashIV;

    return result;
}

//source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.security.cryptography.aes(v=vs.110).aspx
private static string EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
{
    if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
    if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
    if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

    byte[] encrypted;

    using (AesManaged aesAlg = new AesManaged())
    {
        aesAlg.Key = Key;
        aesAlg.IV = IV;

        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

        using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt =
                    new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                {
                    swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                }
                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
    return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
}

//source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.security.cryptography.aes(v=vs.110).aspx
private static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(string cipherTextString, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
{
    byte[] cipherText = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherTextString);

    if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
    if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
    if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

    string plaintext = null;

    using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
    {
        aesAlg.Key = Key;
        aesAlg.IV = IV;

        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

        using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
        {
            using (CryptoStream csDecrypt =
                    new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                {
                    plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return plaintext;
}
```

Y lo que tengo en Node js por ahora es esto:

```
var sys = require ('sys'),
url = require('url'),
http = require('http'),
qs = require('querystring');
crypto = require('crypto-js');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var sql = require('mssql');
const getConn = require('./configVariables');

var config={
    server : getConn.getServer(),
    database : getConn.getDatabase(),
    user : getConn.getUser(),
    password : getConn.getPass(),
    port:getConn.getPort(),
    options: {
        encrypt: false
    }
};

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    try{
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html;charset=UTF-8"});

        var key = "Z8,omB0pxZwñ3h9s";
        var secret = "ZZZZZZ";
        e1 = crypto.AES.encrypt(secret, key, {mode: crypto.mode.CBC, padding: crypto.pad.Pkcs7});
        console.log("key: " + crypto.enc.Base64.stringify(e1.key));
        console.log("iv: " + crypto.enc.Base64.stringify(e1.iv));
        console.log("salt: " + crypto.enc.Base64.stringify(e1.salt));
        console.log("ciphertext: " + crypto.enc.Base64.stringify(e1.ciphertext));
        p = crypto.AES.decrypt(e1, key, {mode: crypto.mode.CBC, padding: crypto.pad.Pkcs7});
        console.log("decrypted: " + crypto.enc.Utf8.stringify(p));        
        var isResponse = JSON.stringify({StatusCode:"200", info:"true", values:p})
        res.end(isResponse);
    }catch(err){
        var errorResponse = JSON.stringify({StatusCode:"400", Descripcion:"ERROR: " + err})
        res.end(errorResponse);
    }
}).listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Si cifro en .NET, la variable ZZZZZZ me da el resultado que necesito. Pero en Node js, aunque el resultado puede ser un poco similar, no es el mismo que obtengo en .NET y realmente necesito obtener exactamente el mismo resultado tanto para el cifrado como para el descifrado.

Por favor necesito ayuda. No me las arreglo para nada en lo que es la encriptación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En .NET C# la hashKey es un arreglo de 32 bytes la cual proviene de una cadena de texto llave de un largo de 16. Pero el hashIV es un arreglo equivalente a la mitad inicial del arreglo de la hashKey.

Entonces en Node.js el algoritmo a utilizar es de 'aes-256-cbc' asignando a las variables keystring y IV el Buffer.from de bytes correspondientes a cada una, las cuales deben ser las mismas que en C#.

A continuación dejo la solución de Node.js que me entregó el mismo resultado.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
algorithm = "aes-256-cbc",
keystring = Buffer.from([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]),
iv = Buffer.from([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ,6 ,7 ,8 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]);
inputEncoding = 'utf8',
outputEncoding = 'base64';

function Encrypt(text) {
    let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm,keystring, iv);
    let encrypted = cipher.update(text, inputEncoding, outputEncoding)
    encrypted += cipher.final(outputEncoding);
    return encrypted;
}

function Decrypt(encrypted) {
    let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm,keystring, iv)
    let dec = decipher.update(encrypted, outputEncoding, inputEncoding)
    dec += decipher.final(inputEncoding);
    return dec;
}

var enc = Encrypt("ZZZZZZ");
console.log("enc: " + enc);
var dec = Decrypt(enc);
console.log("dec: " + dec);
```

Los bytes especificados en la respuesta no son realmente los que capturé desde .NET C#, pero los dejé así a modo de ejemplo.

Si le sirve a alguien más, genial. Dale un voto =)